# <input> box keeps dropping to the next line with float: right

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the input box's to line up with their text, the second input box drops a line and throws everything off when float: right is on. I'd like to know why it skipping a line and how to fix it please. Thank you.

tried rearranging, tried clearfix.

https://jsfiddle.net/dpq1fzcj/4/

```
<section>
    <h1>&nbsp</h1>
    <div id="controls" class="controls">
        <form id="add-book-form">
            Title:
            <input type="text" name="title" required /><br>
            Author:
            <input type="text" name="author" required /><br>
            Pages:
            <input type="text" name="pages" type="number" required /><br>
            Read:
            <input type="checkbox" name="read" /><br>
            <input type="submit" id="add-book-btn" value="Add"> <button onclick="hideForm()">nvm</button>
        </form>
        <button onclick="addBookForm()">Add Book</button>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems.

First, you're floating right the input fields and leaving labels to figure out what to do. First label ends up ok, second up breaks the flow because it fits in the same row as the input field since the text line-height is smaller than height of the input field. But the input field doesnt fit in that same line as its label.

Second, you're using `<br>` for breakings instead of wrapping everything in some kind of a block element.

Third, you're not using `label` tag at all.

So, to fix this:

1. Add labels (and `for` property in labels)
2. Float labels left and inputs right.
3. Add div around every label/input pair and add clearfix to it.
4. Lose `<br>` altogether.